# Meteorjs - routes not working when deployed (Modulus.io) but fine on .meteor.com and local

Tags: meteor, deployment, iron-router, modulus.io

Hi I'm very confused and probably have made a stupid mistake, but for the life of me I can't get my Meteorjs app to work when deployed to Modulus.

On the local host and deployed to Meteor (*.meteor.com) it works just fine, however when deployed to Modulus I get the standard ironrouter error message (oops, looks like there is no route on the client or the server for url http://xyz)

In the browser console I also get an error message: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ServiceConfiguration' of undefined'

Weirdly, the 'admin' package I am using (houston:admin) does work correctly, so I'm guessing it must be a weird mistake I am making.

My routes are defined globally as follows:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});





Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  template: 'home'
});

Router.route('actionSheet');
  Router.route('backdrop');
  Router.route('forms', {
    data: function () {
      return {
        post: Posts.find().fetch()[0]
      };
    }
  });
  Router.route('insertGymForm', {
    data: function() {
    var gyms = Gyms.findOne({createdBy: Meteor.userId()});
    return gyms;
  }
  });
  Router.route('updateGymForm', {
    data: function() {
    var gyms = Gyms.findOne({createdBy: Meteor.userId()});
    return gyms;
  }
  });
  Router.route('headersFooters');
  Router.route('lists');
  Router.route('loading');
  Router.route('modal');
  Router.route('navigation');
  Router.route('navigation.one', {path: '/navigation/one'});
  Router.route('navigation.two', {path: '/navigation/two'});
  Router.route('navigation.three', {path: '/navigation/three'});
  Router.route('popover');
  Router.route('popup');
  Router.route('sideMenu');
  Router.route('slideBox');
  Router.route('spinner');
  Router.route('tabs.one', {path: '/tabs/one', layoutTemplate: 'tabsLayout'});
  Router.route('tabs.two', {path: '/tabs/two', layoutTemplate: 'tabsLayout'});
  Router.route('tabs.three', {path: '/tabs/three', layoutTemplate: 'tabsLayout'});
  Router.route('tabs.four', {path: '/tabs/four', layoutTemplate: 'tabsLayout'});
  Router.route('userAccounts');
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. For me the solution was to not have an "@" in the DB-username (the default suggested DB-username for some reason is your email-address).